# splitting a string using strtok()

Tags: c

I have a string I would like to split into two different strings, the delimiter is `$$$`.
For instance: `milk $$$ 45`
On the left side is the product name and on the right is its quantity. 
I've used `strtok` to split the string but I can't extract the number unfortunately.

```
int num;
char *token = strtok(str, DELIMITER);
printf("%s\n", token);
strcpy(component->name, token);
char *number = strtok(NULL, "       ");
num = atoi(number);
printf("%s\n", number);
```

The `printf` calls are for debugging.

Comment: If the second argument to the second call to `strtok()` contains a blank and a tab, please learn to write `" \t"` instead — it is clearer.  If it contains multiple blanks, it is pointless to repeat delimiters (but it is also harmless apart from marginally slowing the processing).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you start off with a string like this (blanks in the string don't materially affect the argument):

```
 milk$$$45
```

Assuming `DELIMITER` is `"$"` (repeating the dollar sign as in `"$$$"` won't make it look for multiple `$` signs), then after that, you have:

```
milk\0$$45
```

The search in the second `strtok()` continues at the first remaining `$`.  It isolates the token `$$45` with no spaces.  (If there's a space before the number, then it isolates the token `$$` instead.)  When you pass `$$45` to `atoi()`, it is evaluated as `0`.  You could see this for yourself with `printf("[[%s]]\n", number);`.

You should probably fix it by using:

```
char *number = strtok(NULL, " \t$");
```

This will skip leading blank, tab, `$` characters, and then stop at the next one (or the null byte at the end of the string).  Note that the code does not ensure that there are 3 `$` signs separating the name and the number.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt debug your code but using `strtok_r()` its better and more intuitive. C provides two functions `strtok()` and `strtok_r()` for splitting a string by some delimiter.

**strtok_r()**

Just like `strtok()` function in C, `strtok_r()` does the same task of parsing a string into a sequence of tokens. `strtok_r()` is a `reentrant` version of strtok()

**function Signature**

`char *strtok_r(char *str, const char *delim, char **saveptr);`

The third argument `saveptr` is a pointer to a `char *` 
variable that is used internally by `strtok_r()` in 
order to maintain context between successive calls
that parse the same string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /*for the strtok function*/
#include <ctype.h> /*for the isalpha function*/
int main()
{
    /*assume your string is a raw string just like the one bellow. and if its not.
    please modify the code.
    */
    char str[80] = "milk $$$ 45 meat $$$ 89 water $$$ 12";
    const char* delim = " $$$ ";
    char* token = NULL;
    char* rest = str;
    int num;

    while ((token = strtok_r(rest, " $$$ ", &rest)))
    {
        /*if its a number we will convert it to integer number*/
        if (!isalpha(token[0]))
        {
            num = atoi(token);
            printf("The price is: %d\n",num);
        }
        /*else it is a string*/
        printf("The prodact name is: %s\n", token);

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that POSIX defines [`strtok_r()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok_r.html); it is not a part of Standard C.  Microsoft provides `strtok_s()` which, apart from the spelling of the name, is the same as `strtok_r()`.  Standard C (C11 and later) defines `strtok_s()` in (optional but normative) Annex K.  Sadly, it has a different interface from both the POSIX and the Microsoft functions.

Answer (score 0):

You want to split the input string on a delimiter string `$$$`: `strtok()` is not a precise solution for this because it does not search for a delimiter string, but considers any sequence of characters from the delimiter string as a delimiter. Passing `"$$$"` is equivalent to passing just `"$"`. since the second call uses a different set of delimiters (white space), the `strtok()` will return `$$` as the second token, so you get `0` after conversion with `atoi()`.

There are different ways to address this problem.

- use `"$"` or `"$ \t"` as the delimiter set for the second call to `strtok()`. This is sloppy but will work in your case because the second field does not contain embedded spaces and `atoi` ignores leading white space.

  ```
  int num;
  char *token = strtok(str, "$");
  if (token) {
      printf("%s\n", token);
      strcpy(component->name, token);
      char *number = strtok(NULL, "$");
      if (number) {
          num = atoi(number);
          printf("%s\n", number);
      }
  }
  ```
- use `strstr` to locate the delimiter string and skip that to get the second part:

  ```
  int num;
  char *token = str;
  char *p = strstr(str, "$$$");
  if (p) {
      p = '\0';
      p += 3;
  }
  printf("%s\n", token);
  strcpy(component->name, token);
  char *number = p;
  if (number) {
      num = atoi(number);
      printf("%s\n", number);
  }
  ```
- write a custom function to split the string on a delimiter string, and trim white space for consistency:

  ```
  #include <string.h>
  #include <ctype.h>

  char *trim_token(char *str) {
      if (str) {
          size_t len = strlen(str);
          while (len > 0 && isspace((unsigned char)str[-1])
              str[--len] = '\0';
          while (isspace((unsigned char)str[0])
              str++;
      }
      return str;
  }

  char *get_token(char *str, const char *delim, char **context) {
      if (!str)
          str = context;
      if (!str)
          return NULL;   // no more tokens
      char *p = strstr(str, delim);
      if (p) {
          *p = '\0';
          p += strlen(delim);
      }
      *context = p;
      // trimming starting and trailing white space from the token is
      //   a good idea, just return str to preserve these spaces.
      return trim_token(str);
  }
  ```

  and use it this way:

  ```
  int num;
  char *context;
  char *token = get_token(str, "$$$", &context);
  if (token) {
      printf("%s\n", token);
      strcpy(component->name, token);
  }
  char *number = get_token(NULL, "$$$", &context);
  if (number) {
      num = atoi(number);
      printf("%s\n", number);
  }
  ```